# Error in Maven installation

Tags: maven

I have finished to install Maven 3.0.4, and the JDK 6u35 x86 (my computer is a 32-bit).

My environment variables are :

```
JAVA_HOME : C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_35    
M2_HOME : C:\apache-maven-3.0.4    
MAVEN_OPTS : -Xmx1024M –XX :MaxPermSize=256M    
Path : %M2_HOME%\bin;%JAVA_HOME%\bin;
```

When I run `mvn -version` in the command prompt, I have the follow error message :

[image]

Somebody help me!

Comment: Strange class name. Have you tried with another maven distribution ?

Comment: Yes, i have used several versions, same error :(

Comment: Did you try without space in -XX option. It should be `–XX:MaxPermSize=256M` and not `–XX :MaxPermSize=256M`. can you try, I am just guessing here.